# Button to refresh page without JavaScript

Tags: html

How would I make a button that refreshes the page **without** using JavaScript?

I was thinking using a form like this, although it adds a question mark to the URL once you click it:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add an anchor `<a>` using the same page url

Comment: @ArthurAlmeida Ah, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<form>
    <a href="page URL"><button>Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="">
<button type="submit">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby on Rails folks:

`<%= link_to 'Reload', request.original_url %>`